# Как организовать работу git между хостингом и локальной машиной?

Tags: git

У меня есть сайт на хостинге. Хочу сделать так, чтобы с помощью git можно было push'ить данные с локальной машины сразу на хостинг, без использования gihub, соответственно, чтобы на хостинге была возможность данные сохранять (fetch/pull).

PS: На хостиге, который я использую можно использовать терминал, прям в браузере (разработчики постарались)

Короче, я решил это так:
Создал на сервере 2 git-репозитория. Один - в рабочем каталоге, другой вне его:
Первый обычным способом:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
```

Второй на директорию выше:

```
git --bare init
```

Далее добавил этот "голый" ("bare") репозиторий как удалённый к первому:

```
git remote add hub путь/к/bare-репозиторию
git push hub master
```

Затем на локальной машине сделал ssh-доступ к своему хостинг-аккаунту, путём генерации ключей ssh-keygen и добавления публичного ключа в файл authorized_keys на сервере.

Потом скопировал все файлы командой:

```
git clone ssh://hostXXXXXXX@servXX.мой-хостинг.ru/home/hostXXXXXXX/мой-домен/bare-репозиторий
```

Далее внёс необходимые изменения и запушил их стандартным способом

```
git add .
git commit -m "Second commit"
git push origin master
```

Чтобы скопировать данные в рабочий проект, просто выполнил на серваке:

```
git pull hub master
```

На этом всё!

Comment: Очень хороший способ, что бы Ваш сайт было легко сломать/слить исходники. Оно Вам нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь bare репу в домашней папке. Делаешь доступ по ключам в ссх. Добавляшь ремот на компе в эту репу. Через git clone создаешь рабочую папку на сервере.

Comment: Рекомендую расписать поподробнее. Пока тянет скорее на комментарий, чем на полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть доступ по SSH, то на хостинге не нужно даже git-сервер. Клиент может заливать ревизии в репозиторий по файловому протоколу.

Если хочется, чтобы при каждом push'е файлы автоматически разворачивались на http-сервере, то такая возможность есть.

В GIT, начиная с версии 2.3 появилась возможность push'ить в не-bare репозиторий.

Если при этом в целевом репозитории выставлена настройка `receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead`, то локальная копия автоматически обновится.

Более подробно уже дан ответ на [английской версии StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764380/how-to-push-to-a-non-bare-git-repository)